# Slow scroll for anchors

Tags: jquery

I have found this script for anchors on my page

```
$('.anchor').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  var target = $(href);
  var top = target.offset().top;
  $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: top
  });
});
```

But, when i click on `<div class="anchor">`, my page jumps to the position.
Is it possible to slow this scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
$('html,body').animate({
   scrollTop: top
}, "slow");
```

[.animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method looks like this.

> .animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )

By default the durations look like this

slow - 600, normal - 400, fast - 200.

If they are not suitable for your case then you can give your own duration